# MariaDB, DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not saving

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have a MariaDB version `10.2.13-MariaDB-10.2.13+maria~jessie`, with a table `ids`. The table's create code is:

```
CREATE TABLE `ids` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lastupdate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, # for some reason this is being ignored
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

When the table is created, the `lastupdate` column's default value is not set. In fact, looking at the `CREATE` code in HeidiSQL, I see `... DEFAULT '' ...`.

Furthermore, the following query runs without error, but does not affect the table

```
ALTER TABLE ids
MODIFY lastupdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

whereas this one works completely fine

```
ALTER TABLE ids
MODIFY lastupdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

. What could be going wrong here?

*Implementation detail:* The database is being run inside a docker container trivially extended from the default `mariadb` image.

Comment: It works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5SUJWmWQg4h3q7oriQrkyK/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an issue with HeidiSQL (or this particular version of HeidiSQL), not an issue with MariaDB itself.

You can verify this by using the MariaDB client (mysql) and run your `CREATE TABLE` query and then:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE ids;
```

Comment: It works fine on other databases running older versions of MariaDB, so I assumed that couldn't be the case. However, updating HeidiSQL fixed the issue, so it looks like it's an issue with that specific HeidiSQL/MariaDB version combination. Thanks!